# i need to let form errors to be shown on my bootstrap modal template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have made LoginView as CBV approach, and try to validate the credentials of the user plus adding some validations on the email_address. my problem is when I raise ValidationError the errors haven't appeared on the template.
p.s: I don't want to use Ajax solution.i just need to use the Django rendering form error messages solution.

the errors messages are printed on the terminal.

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>__all__<ul class="errorlist nonfield"><li>crediantials errror</li></ul></li></ul>
```

my views.py:

```
class LoginView(FormView):

     form_class = login_page
     template_name = 'login.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('home')


    def get_form_kwargs(self,*args,**kwargs):

        kwargs=super().get_form_kwargs(*args,**kwargs)
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs

   def form_valid(self, form):

      return 
      JsonResponse({"case":'valid','to_page':self.get_success_url()})


    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print(form.errors)
        print(form.non_field_errors())
        print(form['Email'].errors)
        return super().form_invalid(form)
```

my forms.py:

```
class login_page(forms.Form):
    Email = forms.EmailField(required=True,widget=forms.EmailInput(
    attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Email address", "id": "exampleInputEmail2"}))
    Password = 
    forms.CharField(required=True,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs= . 
    {"class": "form-control",'id':'exampleInputPassword2',
                        "placeholder": "Password"}))


    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):  
         self.request=kwargs.pop('request',None)
         super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)




    def clean(self):
         email = self.cleaned_data.get('Email',None)
         password = self.cleaned_data.get('Password',None)

         user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

         if user is not None:

              login(self.request, user)

        else:

             print("crediantials errror")
             raise forms.ValidationError("crediantials errror")

        return self.cleaned_data

    def clean_Email(self):

        if (self.cleaned_data.get('Email', '')
            .endswith('hotmail.com')):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid email address.")

    return self.cleaned_data.get('Email', '')
```

my template

```
<div class="row div_Modal">
    <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade loginModal-content col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="loginModal-content">
            <div class="loginModal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4> </div><div class="loginModal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"> via <div class="social-buttons">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
                {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                </div>or



                    <form class="form" role="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav"> {% csrf_token %}

                    <div class="form-group">

                        {% if form.Email.errors %}
                            <p>qergihghjergehgrhebgrh</p>
                            <ol>
                            {% for error in form.Email.errors %}
                                <li><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>
                            {% endfor %}
                            </ol>
                        {% endif %}
                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>

                        {{ form.Email }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.Password.errors }}
                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>

                        {{ form.Password }}
                        <div class="help-block text-right">
                            <a href="">Forgot the password ?</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
                            </label>


                        </div>
                    </form>



                </div>
                <div class="bottom text-center"> New here ?
                    <a href="signUp.html"><b>Join Us</b></a> </div></div></div>
            <div class="loginModal-footer">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Chris the indentation in my code is correct , maybe here i have mistaken in the indentation

Comment: @ChrisI have adjusted it

Comment: please I need your help guys, I still didn't reach out to a solution